# Should I Box or unbox in the assert?

Tags: java, unboxing

Assuming that I have a method `foo`:

```
public Integer foo () { return 1; }
```

Which of the above to options is lesser expensive? Boxing or unboxing?

```
assert(1, (int) foo()));
```

vs.

```
assert((Integer)3, foo());
```

Comment: Is this just a simple example to make the question easier to understand or is this the real case? This is waaaaaay too micro-optimization. Pick the most readable, easier to understand way. Even if there is a performance difference (because there probably isn't), if you ran that code a thousand times, you'd get a difference in the scale of nanoseconds!

Comment: Why are you returning an `Integer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think primitive type variable comparison is more faster than object comparison. also boxing will take more time to create wrapper object. so you should use unboxing in your assertion.

Answer (score 6):

> Which of the above to options is lesser expensive? Boxing or unboxing?

You are focusing on the wrong question when you ask which is **less** expensive. This is an example of premature optimization, and using the wrapper class will have a slight impact on performance. So, if you want to optimize you should be using the primitive `int`.

```
public int foo () { return 1; }
```

And don't try and optimize assertions, they can (and probably should) be disabled in a production environment.

Information from `java -help`

> ```
> java -help | grep assertions
>
> -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
> -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
>               enable assertions with specified granularity
> -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
> -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
>               disable assertions with specified granularity
> -esa | -enablesystemassertions
>               enable system assertions
> -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
>               disable system assertions
> ```